# import json file in laravel in vue component

Tags: json, import, vue.js, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to import a json file in my vue component but its giving this error

> ERROR in
>   ./~/buble-loader?{"objectAssign":"Object.assign"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/src/App.vue
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/incomingData.json' in
>   '/var/www/html/mac/resources/assets/src'

script:

```
import jsonData from 'assets/incomingData.json'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      entryData: jsonData,
      outputData: ''
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.commit('setEntryData', this.entryData['bundle'])
    this.$store.commit('setTargetRate', this.entryData.targetNetRate)
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.$store.dispatch('calculate').then(res => {
      this.outputData = this.$store.getters.getCalculatedData
    })
  }
}
```

folder structure:

[image]

package.json

[image]

any suggestions how do I fix this issue ?

Comment: Move assets into `pubilc` folder and try like `import jsonData from '/assets/incomingData.json'`

Comment: Is App.vue is inside `store` folder ?

Comment: @user2486 : yes `App.vue` is in store folder

Comment: @06011991 are you sure about that? Doesn't look like in the image.

Comment: @yuriy636 : yeah sorry it was outside . I'm lil confused .

Comment: @06011991 : can you minimize and check again ?

Comment: @06011991 : so just check by using `import jsonData from 'assets/incomingData.json'` ? without `..` double dot

Comment: @user2486 : Yes i checked just now by removing `. .` still the same error

Comment: update your question what you changed ? I assume you removed `/` slash also and tried exact as said in above comment ?

Comment: @user2486 : updated please check it once

Answer (score 0):

The `assets` folder is at the same level as your `App.vue` file (which you are importing the json file from).

In order to import something from the same level, you start your import  path with `./`

```
import jsonData from './assets/incomingData.json'
```

If you don't use `./` webpack will try to find a package in `node_modules` named "assets", instead of a folder.

Comment: Okay! i tried using `./` then i have gotten thsi error `ERROR in ./resources/assets/src/assets/incomingData.json
Module parse failed: /var/www/html/mac/resources/assets/src/assets/incomingData.json Unexpected token (2:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
`

Comment: @06011991 that is probably due to your webpack config not being prepared to parse JSON. Did you use any template in order to create your project?

Comment: Could you just tell me what do you mean by template ?

Comment: A template (well, named as such at least in Vue) is a prepared folder with subfolders, files and configuration that allow you to easily create your project. Looking at the Laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/frontend) I see it uses one (in backend the term is scaffolding, I guess) when creating a project. You may need to look for more info by searching for specific questions to that configuration. You probably need to check `json-loader` configuration.

Comment: Yeah Even I've installed `json loader` though still the error and yes I'm using template for the vue